# Interpolation with nearly duplicate points

Tags: interpolation

I have data sets with very close values and I am getting the error that points are being duplicated. Here is a small part of one data set.

```
 data = {{1.880167859175211`, 0.07717769628585`}, {1.9031673299071004`,
     0.07321050510180123`}, {1.9589651339133867`, 
    0.06358591161773906`}, {2.0039652605902973`, 
    0.05582381535409813`}, {2.0039652605902973`, 
    0.05582381535409813`}, {2.0039652605903098`, 
    0.05582381535409601`}, {2.0039652606025786`, 
    0.05582381535197977`}, {2.0101043764185507`, 
    0.054764875934334406`}, {2.0101043764222215`, 
    0.054764875933701225`}};
Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
```

The solution is to try `DeleteDuplicatesBy` but when I try this I still get the error

```
Interpolation[DeleteDuplicatesBy[data, First], 
 InterpolationOrder -> 1]

Interpolation::inddp: The point 2.0039652605902973` in dimension 1 is duplicated.
```

When I look at differences I can see that there are some close points but they are not zero.

```
Differences@DeleteDuplicatesBy[data, First]


{{0.0229995, -0.00396719}, {0.0557978, -0.00962459}, {0.0450001, \
-0.0077621}, {1.24345*10^-14, -2.1233*10^-15}, {1.22689*10^-11, \
-2.11624*10^-12}, {0.00613912, -0.00105894}, {3.67084*10^-12, \
-6.33181*10^-13}}
```

Is there an obvious way forward? This is just a small part of what I am hitting repeatedly. Is there an easy way of deleting close points to some criterion that `Interpolation` would be happy with?

Thanks

Comment: You can use some threshold to decide when to remove adjacent points. One way is like this. `In[595]:= Split[data, Abs[#1[[1]] - #2[[1]]] < .0001 &][[All, 1]]

Out[595]= {{1.88017, 0.0771777}, {1.90317, 0.0732105}, {1.95897, 
  0.0635859}, {2.00397, 0.0558238}, {2.0101, 0.0547649}}`

Comment: I don't know anything about the internal workings of Interpolation, but just based on the message, it seems clear that it doesn't want values in the first dimension that are that close together. So, one thing you could try is make your duplicate detector less precise, like maybe `DeleteDuplicatesBy[data, Rationalize[First@#, 1/1000] &]`. I don't kow if that'll scale with your data or whether it makes sense in your context.

Comment: Consider points duplicates if their first values are the same. `data2 = DeleteDuplicates[data, #1[[1]] == #2[[1]] &];`

Comment: Confirming @BobHanlon's solution. `Interpolation[DeleteDuplicates[data, #1[[1]] == #2[[1]] &]]` works.  Note "==" is "approximately equal to within numerical precision"

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/181424/interpolation-of-data

Comment: Alternative: `Interpolation[DeleteDuplicatesBy[SetPrecision[data, $MachinePrecision], First], InterpolationOrder -> 1]`

Comment: Variation on @Daniel's approach: `Interpolation[Mean /@ Split[data, Abs[(#1[[1]] - #2[[1]])/#2[[1]]] < 10^-10 &]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortest solution I am aware of for deduplicating a *data* list such as yours is:

```mma
data = {
    {1.880167859175211,  0.07717769628585},
    {1.9031673299071004, 0.07321050510180123},
    {1.9589651339133867, 0.06358591161773906},
    {2.0039652605902973, 0.05582381535409813},
    {2.0039652605902973, 0.05582381535409813},
    {2.0039652605903098, 0.05582381535409601},
    {2.0039652606025786, 0.05582381535197977},
    {2.0101043764185507, 0.054764875934334406},
    {2.0101043764222215, 0.054764875933701225}};

Interpolation[
  DeleteDuplicatesBy[data,
    Rationalize[#1[[1]], 2^(-46)] & ],
  InterpolationOrder -> 1]
```

After a close reading of *DeleteDuplicates* (note, no *By*), using Mathematica's *Equal* test instead of the *Rationalize* based test that I used previously:

```mma
Interpolation[
 DeleteDuplicates[data, #1[[1]] == #2[[1]] &],
  InterpolationOrder -> 1]
```

The above method can be used in $\mathbb{R}^n,\ n>1$ interpolation:

```mma
Interpolation[
 DeleteDuplicates[data, #1[[;;n]] == #2[[;;n]] &],
  InterpolationOrder -> 1]
```

```
{{1.8801679, 0.077177696}, {1.9031673, 0.073210505}, {1.9589651, 
  0.063585912}, {2.0039653, 0.055823815}, {2.0039653, 
  0.055823815}, {2.0101044, 0.054764876}, {2.0101044, 0.054764876}}

InterpolatingFunction[{{1.880167859175211, 2.0101043764222215`}}, {5, 
  7, 0, {7}, {2}, 0, 0, 0, 0, Automatic, {}, {}, 
  False}, {{1.880167859175211, 1.9031673299071004`, \
1.9589651339133867`, 2.0039652605902973`, 2.0039652606025786`, \
2.0101043764185507`, 2.0101043764222215`}}, \
{Developer`PackedArrayForm, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {
  0.07717769628585, 0.07321050510180123, 0.06358591161773906, 
  0.05582381535409813, 0.05582381535197977, 0.054764875934334406`, 
  0.054764875933701225`}}, {Automatic}]
```

No error messages were generated.

[*Equal*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html) states: "Approximate numbers with machine precision or higher are considered equal if they differ in at most their last seven binary digits (roughly their last two decimal digits)." [*IEEE 754 Double Precision binary floating numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) generally have 53 binary in their mantissas. The use of 2^(-46) basically causes a truncation to 46 bits, $53 - 7 == 46$.

```mma
toHex = Function[n, StringJoin[
     (Characters["0123456789ABCDEF"][[#1 + 1]] & ) /@ 
      Flatten[Reverse[IntegerDigits[Normal[ExportByteArray[n, 
           "Real64"]], 16, 2]]]]];
```

The purpose of **toHex** is to produce a hexadecimal representation of the bits of IEEE-754 double precision binary floating point number.

Bwlow, I selected one of the numbers from the *data* list. I show the hexadecimal representation of that number and of some *nearby* decimal numbers to illustrate how much change is needed to change the hexadecimal representation and how much more change is needed to make the numbers different in the *Wolfram Mathematica* equality sense.

```
toHex[0.055823815354098130]

3FAC94F06A914D77

toHex[0.055823815354098128]

3FAC94F06A914D76

0.055823815354098926`18. == 0.055823815354098130

True

toHex[0.055823815354098136]

3FAC94F06A914D78

0.055823815354098130 == 0.055823815354098136

True

0.055823815354098926`18. == 0.055823815354098130

True

0.055823815354098927`18. == 0.055823815354098130

False
```

QED

I recommend reading material like [Forman S. Acton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forman_S._Acton)'s [*Real Computing Made Real: Preventing Errors in Scientific and Engineering Calculations*](https://store.doverpublications.com/0486152936.html). Another resource [Testing equality of two floats: Realistic example](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/25516/testing-equality-of-two-floats-realistic-example).

```mma
ClearAll[toFloat]; 
toFloat[s_String /; StringLength[s] == 16 && 
     StringFreeQ[s, RegularExpression["[^0-9A-Fa-f]"]]] := 
  Block[{sign, exponent, mantissa}, 
   exponent = ToExpression[StringJoin["16^^", 
       StringTake[s, 3]]];
   sign = If[exponent >= 2048, 
      exponent -= 2048; -1., 1.]; exponent -= 1024; 
   mantissa = ToExpression[StringJoin["16^^1", 
       StringTake[s, -13]]];
   SetPrecision[
     sign*2^(exponent - 51)*mantissa, 55]]
```

```mma
toHex[1 + $MachineEpsilon]

(*"3FF0000000000001"*)

toHex[0.1]

(*"3FB999999999999A"*)

toFloat["3FB999999999999A"]

(*0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625`55.*)

N[toFloat["3FB999999999999A"]]

(*0.1`*)

toFloat["3FB9999999999999"]

(*0.09999999999999999167332731531132594682276248931884765625`55.*)

N[toFloat["3FB9999999999999"]]

(*0.1`*)
```

Another trap for the unaware is the sometimes vast differences in concepts of computer floating numbers (which are effectively limited range integers) and what is taught about real number. Computers do not have infinite precision!

Comment: This is a very helpful answer, thank you. I was unsure about what value to use for checking equality and you have sorted this out. The use of `Rationalize`  deals with the issue for numbers of differing magnitude. As far as you are aware is Mathematica consistent for all instances where it is necessary to check equality?  I guess `WorkingPrecision` is involved, e.g. for root finding, if equality is defined with fewer digits.

Comment: @Hugh As far as I am aware *SetPrecision*, *WorkingPrecision*, etc. have not effect on the real number equality test.

Comment: Tolerance of `Equal` is given by ```Internal`Internal`$EqualTolerance``` which is set to `2.10721` by default. Sginificantly increasing its value, for example ```Internal`$EqualTolerance = 16```, will make `4. == 5.` return `True`.